# Customize Image Toolbar CKEditor5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-plugin

Is there any way to customize ImageToolbar so that the alignments are via style in the img tag?

Or to modify the behavior of the predefined styles?

I can think of something like:

```js
const ImageStyle = editor.commands.get('ImageStyle')

ImageStyle.alignCenter = (imageTag){
 ....
}
```

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.